# How to get the proportion of values in a column >X?

Tags: sqlite

Using sqlite3, I have a column "grades" in table "students" and I want to get the proportion of students who scored over 80 on a test. How do I get that? I can `select count(*) from students and then select count(*) from students where score>80`, but how do I get the proportion in one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do this:

```
SELECT
    AVG(CASE WHEN grades > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM students;
```

This just takes a conditional average over the entire table, counting the number of students with a grade over 80, then normalizing that count by the total number of students.